# Скобки () {} при инициализации внутри класса

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, инициализация, объявление

Подскажите пожалуйста, а есть ли разница между использованием круглых и фигурных скобок при инициализации конструктора внутри класса. Оба варианта работают корректно.

```
class A
{
public:
    char c;
    int d;

    A(char ch)
        :c(ch) {}
    A(char ch, int i)
        :c{ch}, d{i} {}
};

int main()
{
    A first = A('a');
    A second = A('b', 1);

    cout << "First: "  << first.c << endl;
    cout << "Second: " << second.c  << ' ' << second.d << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Начнем с того, что имеются случаи, когда нельзя применять инициализацию одного из видов к членам данных класса.

Например, если у вас имеется член класса, который является агрегатом (структурой или массивом), то возможные виды инициализации ограничены.

Рассмотрим несколько примеров.

В данном примере внутри структуры `A` объявляется агрегатный член данных `B`, имеющий тип структуры. Тогда данное объявление конструктора будет некорректныым

```
struct A
{
    A(int x) : b( x ) {}

    struct B
    {
        int x;
    } b;
};

int main()
{
    A a( 10 );
}
```

Компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке, говорящее о том, что он не может преобразовать объект типа `int` в объект типа `struct B`. Однако если вы замените круглые скобки на фигурные,

```
struct A
{
    A(int x) : b{ x } {}

    struct B
    {
        int x;
    } b;
};

int main()
{
    A a( 10 );
}
```

то код будет успешно компилироваться, так как объект `b` будет инициализирован как агрегат.

Теперь если в конструкторе заменить тип у параметра с `int` на `A::B`, то ситуация изменится.

Данная программа будет успешно компилироваться

```
struct A
{
    struct B;

    A(B x) : b( x ) {}

    struct B
    {
        int x;
    } b;
};

int main()
{
    A::B b = { 10 };
    A a( b );
}
```

так как структуры, которые являются агрегатами, имеют конструктор копирования, создаваемый компилятором неявно.

Иная ситуация складывается, когда членом данных, который представляет собой агрегат, является массив.
Как и в случае со структурой, данная программа не будет компилироваться

```
struct A
{
    struct B;

    A(int x) : b( x ) {}

    int b[1];
};

int main()
{
    int b = 10;
    A a( b );
}
```

так как нет преобразования из целочисленного типа в массив.

Однако если заменить параметр на массив, не важно, является он ссылкой или нет, как показано ниже

```
struct A
{
    struct B;

    A(int x[1]) : b( x ) {}

    int b[1];
};

int main()
{
    int b[1] = { 10 };
    A a( b );
}
```

или

```
struct A
{
    struct B;

    A(int ( &x )[1]) : b( x ) {}

    int b[1];
};

int main()
{
    int b[1] = { 10 };
    A a( b );
}
```

то программа не будет компилироваться, так как в первом случае нет преобразования из указателя в массив, а во втором случае, когда параметр объявлен как ссылка, массивы не имеют конструктора копирования.

Для инициализации члена данных, который является массивом, можно использовать следующую запись

```
struct A
{
    struct B;

    A(int x) : b{ x } {}

    int b[1];
};

int main()
{
    int b = 10;
    A a( b );
}
```

Данная программа успешно скомпилируется. Однако вы не можете запись с фигурными скобками заключить еще в круглые собкки, как показано ниже

```
struct A
{
    struct B;

    A(int x) : b({ x }) {}

    int b[1];
};

int main()
{
    int b = 10;
    A a( b );
}
```

Компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке, так как,  опять-таки, для массивов нет конструктора копирования. Однако для структур такая запись инициализации будет успешно воспринята компилятором, так как структуры, как агрегаты, имеют неявно объявленный компилятором конструктор копирования.

```
struct A
{
    A(int x) : b({ x }) {}

    struct B
    {
        int x;
    } b;
};

int main()
{
    int b = 10;
    A a( b );
}
```

Данная программа успешно скомпилируется.

Для арифметических типов инициализация с фигурными скобками не разрешает "сужение" значения, то есть использовать в качестве инициализатора значение, которое потенциально не может разместиться в инициализируемом объекте.
Поэтому следующая программа не будет компилироваться

```
struct A
{
    A(int x) : b{ x } {}
    short b;
};

int main()
{
    int b = 10;
    A a( b );
}
```

Причиной ошибки будет то, что объект типа `short` не в состоянии разместить все значения объекта типа `int`, то есть будет иметь место "сужение" инициализирующего значения.

Однако если заменить фигурные скобки на круглые,  то программа успешно скомпилируется

```
struct A
{
    A(int x) : b( x ) {}
    short b;
};

int main()
{
    int b = 10;
    A a( b );
}
```

Когда инициализируемый член класса является определенный пользователем тип, то в дело вступают конструкторы, которые имеют параметр типа `std::initializer_list`

Например, в приведенной ниже программе, когда нет такого конструктора, можно инициализировать член класса как `b( x )`, или как `b{ x }`, или даже как `b( { x } )`

```
struct A
{
    A(int x) : b({ x }) {}

    struct B
    {
        B(int x)
        {
            std::cout << "B( int )" << std::endl;
        }
    } b;
};

int main()
{
    int b = 10;
    A a(b);
}
```

Однако если в классе присутствует конструктор с параметром типа `std::initializer list`, то для инициализаций вида `b{ x }` и `b( { x } )` будет вызван именно он. А для инициализации вида `b( x )` будет вызван другой конструктор.

Например, для этой программы

```
struct A
{
    A(int x) : b( x ) {}

    struct B
    {
        B(int x)
        {
            std::cout << "B( int )" << std::endl;
        }
        B(std::initializer_list<int>)
        {
            std::cout << "B( std::initializer_list<int> )" << std::endl;
        }
    } b;
};

int main()
{
    int b = 10;
    A a(b);
}
```

будет выведено сообзение

```
B( int )
```

А для этой программы

```
struct A
{
    A(int x) : b{ x } {}

    struct B
    {
        B(int x)
        {
            std::cout << "B( int )" << std::endl;
        }
        B(std::initializer_list<int>)
        {
            std::cout << "B( std::initializer_list<int> )" << std::endl;
        }
    } b;
};

int main()
{
    int b = 10;
    A a(b);
}
```

будет выведено сообщение

```
B( std::initializer_list<int> )
```

Вообще, эта тема достаточно обширная.

О некоторых причудах инициализации я написал на своем сайте в конце темы [Шутка - ложь, но в ней намек, добрым молодцам урок.](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000047-000-40-0-1475597138)

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например, напишите

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A a(300);
    A b{300};
}
```

Вам сразу сообщат, что второе объявление не годится - поскольку 300 в `char` не поместится. Инициализация с фигурными скобками не разрешает сужающее преобразование.

Есть и другие отличия - например, при фигурных скобках компилятор будет искать конструктор от `initializer_list`. Например, если в вашем классе будет такое:

```
class A {
    vector<int> v;
...
A(int x):v{x} {}
A(int x):v(x) {}
```

то последние две строчки означают совершенно разные вещи - первая - вектор с элементом `x`, а вторая - вектор с `x` элементами...